# How to Map 2013 Workflow Task Data to Update the List Item

Tags: workflow, tasks

We have a workflow started from the creation of a list item.  Essentially we would like some custom input textboxes on the workflow task.  And when the user completes the workflow task, the information they put into those input boxes would be sent to the list item ... the list item should get updated with these values.  This seems like a basic request.  But I can't seem to figure out how to do it in 2013 workflows.  (This functionality used to exist in 2010 workflows.)

I've added some screenshots to help describe the problem.  We have created a custom content type already so that we can have custom buttons for **Classified** and **Questions** (instead of the OOTB Approved and Rejected buttons).

Based on the screenshots, how can I retrieve the value **1234567890** from the completed task, and automatically update the list item with this value in the **HTS US Code** field?

[image: Screenshot of workflow and Task]

[image: Screenshot of the Task in the User Interface]

[image: Screenshot of the list where the value from the task should be populated]